# Separate admin page for one-to-many objects

Tags: python, django

I have the following model:

```
class Campaign:
    ...


class Location:
    ...
    campaign = models.ForeignKey(Campaign)
```

I normally would edit the locations using a tabular inline, but because the number of Locations is very high I would like to move the management of the locations to another page. It should pretty much do the same as normal Admin page, except it should only display Locations for the selected campaign and when adding a new Location, it should be automatically attached to the right Campaign. To access the Location Admin page a link in the Campaigns list should be clicked.

What would be the right way to do this? Are there other options?

Answer (score 0):

There is no out of the box solution for your problem, but it is pretty easy to do.

I would register Locations as a separate model admin object like this:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from models import Location

class LocationAdmin(EnhancedModelAdminMixin, admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_filter = 'campaign', 

admin.site.register(Location, LocationAdmin)
```

This way you will have admin interface where you can filter your locations by campaigns.

To have a direct access to Location on Campaign model admin I would use https://github.com/charettes/django-admin-enhancer

Auto selecting a filtered campaign on new Location create form it is a bit more trickier... But my approach would be to add a query parameter to Add new Location button and then catch it when initializing create form, to define initial value of field campaign.

First of all create a template on let's say your_app/admin/change_list.html, which looks like this:

```
{% extends "admin/change_list.html" %}
{% load i18n admin_static admin_list %}
{% load admin_urls %}

{% block object-tools %}
  {% if has_add_permission %}
    <ul class="object-tools">
      {% block object-tools-items %}
        <li>
          <a href="{% url cl.opts|admin_urlname:'add' %}{% if is_popup %}?_popup=1{% if selected_campaign %}&selected_campaign={{ selected_campaign }}{% endif %}
          {% elif selected_campaign %}?selected_campaign={{ selected_campaign }}{% endif %}"
             class="addlink">
            {% blocktrans with cl.opts.verbose_name as name %}Add {{ name }}{% endblocktrans %}
          </a>
        </li>
      {% endblock %}
    </ul>
  {% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

Then append your LocationAdmin class to look like this:

```
class LocationAdmin(EnhancedModelAdminMixin, admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_filter = 'campaign',
    list_display = 'location_name', 'campaign'

    change_list_template = 'your_app/admin/change_list.html'

    def changelist_view(self, request, extra_context=None):
        if 'campaign__id__exact' in getattr(request, request.method):
            selected_campaign = getattr(request, request.method)['campaign__id__exact']
            if not extra_context:
                extra_context = {'selected_campaign': selected_campaign}
            else:
                extra_context['selected_campaign'] = selected_campaign
        return super(LocationAdmin, self).changelist_view(request, extra_context)

    def formfield_for_foreignkey(self, db_field, request, **kwargs):
        if db_field.name == 'campaign':
            if 'selected_campaign' in getattr(request, request.method):
                kwargs['initial'] = getattr(request, request.method)['selected_campaign']
                return db_field.formfield(**kwargs)
        return super(LocationAdmin, self).formfield_for_foreignkey(
            db_field, request, **kwargs
        )
```

So what we are doing here is we are overriding modeladmins changelist_view function just to add additional context variable of current 'selected_campaign'.

Then we adding it as a query parameter on Add new Location button.

Finaly we are using model admins formfield_for_foreignkey function to dynamically define initial value of campaign field based on parameter received with request when user clicks on Add new location.

Cheers! Do not forget to up-vote this answer if you feel it was helpful ;)